# SVN status is normal instead of added

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

I have a question regarding svn: I added directory D1 with files F1 and F2 in feature branch. After it I'm trying to merge it back to trunk. After merge files appears in commit window, but they are marked as normal(+) and directory D1 is marked as added. After commit these files are not transfered to server, so build fails. Why these files are marked as normal instead of added?
Thanks!

Some details:

1. Make a branch B1 from trunk Add directory with files in branch B1
2. Merge all changes from trunk to branch for moment of merge Try to
   merge B1 back to trunk
3. Merge branch to trunk back using reintegrate or "merge two different
   trees" option - catch a diff between trunk and branch and put it
   into trunk working copy.
4. Try to commit trunk

Comment: I actually would not necessarily expect any file data to be transferred for the added files, because the server should be able to just "copy" the files from the branch, by creating a link of sorts, if they are not modified. Where does the build fail? Are the files present in your working copy? Did you forget to commit the result of the merge? Your scenario says "try to commit trunk". Did you actually go through with the commit, with the new files checked for commit?

Answer (score 0):

Svn must be told you want to `add` the files to the repository.  It doesn't assume that any file under a revision controlled directory is a revision controlled file.

There are exceptions.  For example, when you add a directory to the repository, the default behavior is to add the directory and everything it contains to the repository.

Now, if you did add the file, typically it is marked with a green plus.  (It is confusing because you indicate it shows up as normal with a green plus sign, and that's not how a normal file shows up).  If you have files that have green pluses, they are added *but not committed*.  This means that at some point in time you did the correct add operation, but you need to commit the file back to the remote repository.

Truly normal (non revision controlled files) show up without any kind of file decoration.

Also certain ways of creating the files go around the operating system's desktop GUI event handler hooks.  If you created the files using DOS utilities then the hook that TortoiseSVN uses to know the file was created will not typically be called.

Finally, the origin of the file must be accounted for to a small degree too.  Dragging and dropping SVN files with TortoiseSVN is typically handled well, with the exception of dragging and dropping SVN files from two different checkouts of a repository, or two different checkouts of two different repositories.  In the latter cases, the operating system's desktop GUI event handlers that TortoiseSVN implements will attempt to move the file in a SVN aware manner, but SVN itself doesn't support revision tracking across different local repositories.

Comment: It was strange for me that I've added these files in branch to the directory, and they are not displayed as added after merge, while parent directory is added...

Comment: @dbf I can't help but wonder if there is some extra, vital, piece of information that is missing to really know what is going on here.  Your description is mostly about what has happened, and is very light on the details of what you did.  Are you sure that what you did before checkin is described completely enough, and that it is not in any way different than what you always do?  Also, I recommend an install of cygwin (to get the command line svn tool) in addition to TortiseSVN, because you get better error reporting.

Comment: Thanks, Edwin. I added some details to original post, looks like it is what I've done.

Comment: @EdwinBuck, you don't need cygwin to get the command-line tool. TortoiseSVN these days ships with a Windows version of the command-line tools.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for the note, that's really good info to know!

Answer (score -1):

I still don't know how to resolve it using tortoise merge, here is a workaround that I discovered:

1. Merge branch to trunk using tortoise merge
2. Prepare patch between current state of trunk and it's previous state (commited)
3. Checkout trunk to separate dir, apply this patch and commit. It was required to add files manually, but at least it was possible to do it (it was not possible to add after merge).

Comment: A merge with added files should just work, adding the files to trunk as well. Applying a patch should not be needed at all, and doing so will lose history of the new files.

Comment: @Ben, what to you mean when you are talking about "a merge with added files"? As I said, these files are not available to be added using svn add (I get an error trying to add them) and it is displayed that there are no changes for these files when I open commit window.

Comment: I mean a merge from a branch, where the branch has added files. The merge operation itself should have added the files for you, and you should see those files in your working copy now. No further action should be needed during the merge, you just need to commit them.